# Azure Active Directory integration error The given key 'app_link' was not present in the dictionary with Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I am integrating Azure Active Directory in my Xamarin Forms project.. as of now i am testing my app for Android. After click on login button i am successfully able to launch login page of microsoft portal but when user logged in after entering their email and password i got **The given key 'app_link' was not present in the dictionary** exception in my app.

[image: Error Image]

Please suggest any solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of the question by google it
I was using

```
string GraphResourceUri = "https//graph.microsoft.com";
```

as url and then i changed it to

```
string GraphResourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";
```

and application start working smoothly.